# How should I transport my electric kick scooter (e-scooter)?

Tags: transport-by-car

The scooter fits inside the car but is awkwardly shaped and takes up a lot of space even when folded down.

I haven't been able to find a tow ball rack that claims to work for an e-scooter.

What's the best way to transport an e-scooter in a car?

Comment: Is this a scooter, or a motorbike ?  Could you just ride the scooter and leave the car at home ?

Comment: Picture of scooter would definitely help. When I read "e-scooter" I picture the ones that are like a razor scooter with an electric motor. Which should be trivial to put in the trunk of a car. But as Criggie notes, if what you mean is the scooter style that's more like a classic Italian Vespa but electric, that's more like transporting a small motorbike with your car, which is definitely NOT trivial.

Comment: My solution to this is that if I have to combine car and riding some two-wheeled vehicle, that two-wheeled vehicle is not an e-scooter but rather a folding Brompton bike. It would be hard to find a car where Brompton won't fit inside.

Comment: Possibly related/kinda dupe of https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/79090/how-do-i-safely-transport-a-very-heavy-e-bike-in-my-car

Comment: I mean an electric kick scooter (edited). It fits in the car but it is awkwardly shaped and takes up a lot of space.

Comment: Get a folding scooter.

Comment: This might end up being somewhat on topic on lifehacks.SE I doubt mechanics.SE would think it on-topic there.

Comment: I would suggest a roof rack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably your scooter looks like this and has measurements similar.

[image] 
  <sup>Image is from https://www.electriq.co.uk/p/e-sc1/electriq-esc1 and illustrates a 25 km/h "kick" scooter with 8 Ah battery representative of the class.</sup>

Half a metre wide and tall, and just over a metre long when folded.

This is approximately equal to a human's torso+head, or a extended leg.

- Lay scooter across the back seat.
- Lie the scooter down in the rear seat foot well
- Stand scooter on end in any unoccupied seat, and use the seatbelt to retain it.
- Stow scooter in the boot/trunk.  An average sedan's boot should hold about 4~6.

An average conventional 4 door sedan should be able to carry 20 of these scooters with some careful stowage presuming there's only a driver.  It's not clear why you're having a problem - its possible your scooter is much larger than the generic one pictured.

If your car is full of passengers and luggage and there is no space anywhere inside, you could try a roof box, or hire a larger car for the journey.

Some journeys may be better serviced by leaving the car at home, and riding the scooter.  It depends on how far you have to go, and what other items you need to take.